# What Im doing wrong in this json request?

Tags: python, json, request, python-requests, urllib

Im trying to get a response from the form in https://www.correoargentino.com.ar/formularios/cpa
Wathing the request header I made the following code:

```
import json, requests


import requests
import logging

try:
    import http.client as http_client
except ImportError:
    # Python 2
    import httplib as http_client

http_client.HTTPConnection.debuglevel = 1
logging.basicConfig()
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
requests_log = logging.getLogger("requests.packages.urllib3")
requests_log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
requests_log.propagate = True


url = "https://www.correoargentino.com.ar/sites/all/modules/custom/ca_forms/api/wsFacade.php/"
code = 'H'
params = dict(
    action="localidades",
    localidad="none",
    calle="",
    altura="",
    provincia=code,
)

resp = requests.get(url=url, params=params,headers={
        'Referer': 'https://www.correoargentino.com.ar/formularios/cpa', 
        'Origin': 'https://www.correoargentino.com.ar',
        'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.162 Safari/537.36',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
        'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
        'X-Requested-With':'XMLHttpRequest',    
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
        'Accept-Language': 'es-419,es;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
        'Cookie': '_ga=GA1.3.2079472460.1521655930; _gid=GA1.3.2041549384.1521655930; has_js=1',
})
print resp.text
```

but I getting error, when I watch the response from Chrome I get the correct response. I fought it was becouse the origin / referer of the request but then I change the headers and keep getting the same error.

Any help is welcome

Comment: Please include the full text of the error (the traceback if it's a python exception).

Comment: The problem is the reCAPTCHA value and the method of request is `POST`

Comment: glibdub the no traceback, the server answer error. You could execute the code to get the request

Comment: @kip in the form when you chose a state, if you inspect networks request, it respond with cities, not reCAPTCHA is click, I need that response that is use to populate the cities select box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changes the method you use to `.post`, remember the second param is `data` in this method

```
resp = requests.post(url=url, data=params)
```